# Having an error on strcpy "address pointing at code space is taken"

Tags: c

```
  #pragma inspect, symbols

  #pragma nolist

  #pragma ENV LIBSPACE

  #include <stdio.h>

  #include <string.h>

  #include <tal.h>

  #include <cextdecs(FILE_OPEN_,FILE_CLOSE_,FILE_GETINFO_,FILENAME_DECOMPOSE_,WRITEX,READX,FILE_SETKEY_,WRITEUPDATEX,FILENAME_RESOLVE_,FILE_SETPOSITION_,PROCESS_GETINFOLIST_,USER_GETINFO_,FILENAME_MATCH_)>

  #include <fcntl.h>

  #include <stdlib.h>

  #include <stddef.h>

  #include <ctype.h>

    #include "$SYSTEM.ZSYSDEFS.ZSYSC (filename_constant,process_itemcodes)"

 #pragma list

   /*VARIABLES*/

          const char program_id_DB[] = "CSRTST";
          const char program_name_DB_c[ZSYS_VAL_LEN_FILENAME] = {"$DSMSCM.CSR.CSRTST"};


/*PROCESS COMMAND FUNCTION*/

processCMD(char string[])
{


struct local_stack_def{

        _cc_status cc;
        char command_E[30];
        char DataEntry[200];
        char  user_id_E[200];
        char curr_vol_subvol[ZSYS_VAL_LEN_FILENAME];
        char program_name_DB[ZSYS_VAL_LEN_FILENAME];
        short ret_attr_count;
        short ret_values_maxlen;
        short user_maxlen;
        char curr_vol_subvol_t;
        int x, j, val1, val2, val3;
        short user_curlen, piece_length, fullname_length;
        short fpointer, error, resultFD,resultFM, resultUGI,resultGIL, resultFR,ret_val_length;
        union {
                   long  id_32;
                   short id_16[2];
                  } user_id;
        struct {
                 short paid;
                 short prgm_len;
                 char  prgm_name_E[ZSYS_VAL_LEN_FILENAME];
                   } ret_vals;

         struct {
           char val[20];
        } command_DB[2];
         struct {
           char val4[50];
        } user_id_DB[2];


        short attr_listX[2];
};

struct local_stack_def l_temp;
struct local_stack_def *l = &l_temp;

strcpy(&l->curr_vol_subvol_t,"x");
```

Comment: Way too much code and way too less question.

Comment: Please simplify your code snippet to the *minimum* required to exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curr_vol_subvol_t` is declared to be `char`.  You can't copy a null-terminated C string `"x"` into a single `char`.  You need a `char` array with at least 2 members, or you can just assign a `char` (e.g. `'x'`) to `curr_vol_subvol_t` if that's what you really want.

Comment: im having the same error for the all printf have any idea why ?!?
if (l->resultGIL != 0){
         printf("FILENAME_RESOLVE_ ERROR #:%d -Error occured.  ", l->resultGIL);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }

Comment: I don't know why that is. Very hard to work out in comments. Ask a new question. This one is done. Try to post less code next time. Cut your example down to a short reproducible block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `curr_vol_subvol_t` is a single `char`, but you're trying to write a `char[2]` (namely `{ 'x', '\0' }`) to it. Don't do that. Just say `l->curr_vol_subvol_t = 'x'.`