# Printf error "address pointing at code space is taken"

Tags: c

Does anyone know what this error means?

```
address pointing at code space is taken.
```

Here is the code that causes it:

```
if (l->resultGIL != 0)
{
    printf("FILENAME_RESOLVE_ ERROR #:%d -Error occured.  ", l->resultGIL);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here is the definition of `l`:

```
struct local_stack_def{ 
    short fpointer, error, resultFD, resultFM, resultUGI, resultGIL, resultFR, ret_val_length; 
}; 

struct local_stack_def l_temp;

struct local_stack_def *l = &l_temp;
```

Comment: What is the type of `l->resultGIL`?

Comment: You forgot to *ask a question*. Don't just throw code at us and expect us to answer. Or care.

Comment: Well Jonathan i was hoping it was simple to notice by the heading that the printf is the issue here and the error is why im posting! Also Sharptooth and Oli the l->result 

struct local_stack_def{
       short fpointer, error, resultFD,resultFM, resultUGI,resultGIL, resultFR,ret_val_length;
     
};

struct local_stack_def l_temp;
struct local_stack_def *l = &l_temp;

Comment: @Ken, I edited your question to make it more question-like, based on the code you offered in your comment. If I've done something wrong, please edit it again yourself.

Comment: Thank you senderle! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Ken: Compiled your code sample on Ideone, and it compiles [correctly](http://www.ideone.com/lwTh1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing as [your post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572492/having-an-error-on-strcpy-address-pointing-at-code-space-is-taken) - the error is most likely not due to this call to printf, but is somewhere else that you have overwritten the bounds of some memory.

You don't say what system this is on (never seen that error before) but try compiling with all the warning levels on and look for memory errors elsewhere